# Select list elements contained in another list in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string with "|" seperators:

```cs
string s = "item1|item2|item3|item4";
```

a list of objects that each have a name and value:

```cs
//object
List<ItemObject> itemList = new List<ItemObject>();
itemList.Add(new ItemObject{Name="item0",Value=0});
itemList.Add(new ItemObject{Name="item1",Value=1});

//class
public class ItemObject(){
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Value {get;set;}
}
```

How could the following code be done in one line in linq?

```cs
var newList = new List<object>();
foreach (var item in s.Split("|"))
{
    newList.Add(itemList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == item));
}

// Result: newList
// {Name="item1",Value=1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to start from splitting the string in the beginning. By doing so we won't split it during each iteration:

```
List<ItemObject> newList = s
  .Split("|")
  .SelectMany(x => itemList.Where(i => i.Name == x))
  .ToList();
```

Or even better:

```
List<ItemObject> newList = s
  .Split("|") // we can also pass second argument: StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries
  .Distinct() // remove possible duplicates, we can also specify comparer f.e. StringComparer.CurrentCulture
  .SelectMany(x => itemList
    .Where(i => string.Equals(i.Name, x))) // it is better to use string.Equals, we can pass comparison as third argument f.e. StringComparison.CurrentCulture
  .ToList();
```

Comment: This is a clever way of using `SelectMany` but it's also where I see the trade-off: it performs multiple iterations through `itemList`. Whether this is better, it really depends on the input data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var newList = itemList.Where(item => s.Split('|').Contains(item.Name));
```

The proposed solution also prevents from populating `newList` with `null`s from nonpresent items. You may also consider a more strict string equality check.

Comment: This solution is not optimal because we will split the string again and again for each itemList item (twice with the given input).

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "item1|item2|item3|item4";
```

I don't see a need for splitting this string `s`. So you could simply do

```
var newList = itemList.Where(i => s.Contains(i.Name));
```

---

For different buggy input you can also do

```
s = "|" + s + "|";
var newList = itemList.Where(o => s.Contains("|" + o.Name + '|')).ToList();
```

Comment: This solution can be buggy for different input data, for example "item11|item2|item3|item4" has "item11" which satisfies Contains but it is not "item1" at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<object> newList = itemList.Where(item => s.Split("|").Contains(item.Name)).ToList<object>();
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?